# MSBuild reexpand property

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I use some custom props file like this (my_super_props.props)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetOsName>linux</TargetOsName>
    <RemoteGeneratedFilesDir>$(RemoteIntDir)generated_files/</RemoteGeneratedFilesDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

VS generates vcxproj file for me like this (piece)

```
.....
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared" />
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='debug|x86'">
    <Import Project="my_super_props.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='debug|x86'">
    <RemoteIntDir>$(RemoteProjectDir)/obj/$(PlatformTarget)/$(TargetOsName)/$(Configuration)/</RemoteIntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  .....
```

Inside Microsoft.Cpp.props - $(RemoteIntDir) already defined like this

```
<RemoteIntDir Condition="'$(RemoteIntDir)' == ''">$(RemoteProjectDir)/obj/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)/</RemoteIntDir>
```

So Inside my Targets i'ev got wrong value of **$(RemoteGeneratedFilesDir)**
for exmaple
**my_proj/obj/x86/debug/generated_files**
instead of
**my_proj/obj/x86/linux/debug/generated_files**

because properties expands at declaration time,
but i can't declare **$(RemoteIntDir)** earlier, cos it depends of **$(TargetOsName)**

So I must somehow reexpand **$(RemoteGeneratedFilesDir)** before targets start - but i don't know how ??

PS
**$(RemoteIntDir)** - filled with Visual Studio project configuraion UI Dialog, so i even can't change order of properties declaration/props imports and etc

Comment: Try putting the property definition inside a target. It should then be expanded, when the target is run.

Comment: One thing which I want to confirm is that the `RemoteIntDir` property does not exist under  my system `Microsoft.Cpp.props` file? Was the `RemoteIntDir` property created by yourself and a new custom property?

Comment: What is your VS version?

Comment: RemoteIntDir inside c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.props which obviously imported inside Microsoft.Cpp.props

I use latest vs2019 with all updates

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are in a mess and there are no default properties `RemoteProjectDir`,`RemoteGeneratedFilesDir`,`RemoteIntDir` on system `Microsoft.Cpp.props` file. So it is quite strange due to your description.

I have added

```
<RemoteIntDir Condition="'$(RemoteIntDir)' == ''">$(RemoteProjectDir)/obj/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)/</RemoteIntDir>
.....
```

into my `Microsoft.Cpp.props` file to keep the same MSBuild environment as yours.

I have two questions.

`my_proj/obj/x86/linux/debug/generated_files`, is your current build configuration is `linux`? And why did you have two similar configuration `linux` and `debug` under it?

**Also**, is it `my_proj/obj/x86/linux/generated_files`?

In this situation, I have trusted your description, and assume it is `my_proj/obj/x86/linux/debug/generated_files`.

Besides,  the changed `$(Configuration)` will act on the whole msbuild files including `Microsoft.Cpp.props` system files and `vcxproj` file.

**One**

If your current **build configuration** is `debug` and Platform is `x86`, you should try to change your `my_super_props.props` file like this:

```
<RemoteGeneratedFilesDir>$(RemoteProjectDir)/obj/$(Platform)/$(TargetOsName)/$(Configuration)/generated_files/</RemoteGeneratedFilesDir>
```

[image]

**Two**

If your build configuration is `linux`(to create it, you have to enter **Build** top menu under VS IDE-->**Configuration Manager**-->click New under the **Project Configuration** then input `linux` under it)

[image]

**First**, you have to add these under your current `vcxproj` file:

```
 <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='linux|x86'">
    <Import Project="my_super_props.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='linux|x86'">
    <RemoteIntDir>$(RemoteProjectDir)/obj/$(PlatformTarget)/$(TargetOsName)/debug/</RemoteIntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Second**, modify your `my_super_props.props` file:

```
<RemoteGeneratedFilesDir>$(RemoteProjectDir)/obj/$(Platform)/$(TargetOsName)/debug/generated_files/</RemoteGeneratedFilesDir>
```

Rebuild the project:

[image]

Comment: linux it's not a configuration! it's just folder in which i want put my generated files

my_proj/obj/x86/linux/debug/generated_files - here x86 platform, debug configuration, and "linux" just my addition to path

Comment: Then, try the solution one and is that help you?

Comment: What's solution? I don't see any solution in your answer. You even did not understand my question!